# How to get final destination URL from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I do an XMLHttpRequest, I always get redirected automatically to the URL (presumably by the headers of the response). For example, if I query "http://www.stackoverflow.com" I will be redirected to "http://stackoverflow.com".

How can I get that final URL? (http://stackoverflow.com/ in the example)

I checked in the response headers but I cannot seem to find it. (I just used the GET/POST method not HEAD).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using jQuery (this is for current page url) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var href = window.location.href.toString();
});
```

EDIT  : For, response page final url, pass jqXHR to ajaxComplete & then read the header.

Comment: I am not trying to find the URL of the page but the URL of an AJAX request. Is there a way?

Comment: Please see EDIT. Is is happening now ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for a location header in the response.

In the example you gave, accessing www.stackoverflow.com and being redirected to stackoverflow.com here is most definatly a Location header being used.

```
[trcjr@rigel ~]$ curl -I http://www.stackoverflow.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 148
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/
Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2011 21:47:17 GMT

[trcjr@rigel ~]$
```

Comment: I checked them. But the server doesn't provide that information. Any alternatives?

Comment: In the example you gave, accessing www.stackoverflow.com and being redirected to stackoverflow.com here is most definatly a Location header being used. See the updated response.